# Unusual ideas for a 10 yr old taking photos on theme of 'Cold'?

Tags: cold

Can anyone help please?! She has a Nikon D60.

Comment: Hi and welcome to photography stackexchange, unfortunately questions that provoke a discussion rather than being something with a definite answer are a poor fit for stackexchange and so are likely to be closed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Somebody sneezing, freeze-frame the spray in profile against a gray background.

Scrap metal: cold rolled steel and "cold iron".

A pile of "cold cash" illuminated bt eerie "cold cathode" lighting.

Comment: Also, the 2015Jan issuenof *Popular Photography* has a feature on photographing ice.